# Brave Browser - Auto-Scrolling

Tags: 20.04, scrolling, mouse-scroll, brave

Is there a way to activate Auto-Scrolling (Middle-click scrolling) on Brave Browser?

I looked everywhere on the settings page, but could not find anything.
All my searched led to activating Auto-Scrolling on Firefox but not on Brave Browser.

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and the latest version of Brave (v 1.21.77).

Comment: First place to ask is a Brave forum.

Comment: Already created a question there. Also with no replies.